# Jupyter pdf export cuts off after one page

Tags: jupyter

I'm trying to export a 3page jupyter notebook to pdf, 
but the downloaded document cuts off after only 1 page.
Print-preview runs fine. 
I don't have more details than this, did you ever get across a bug like this?

I have no idea how to trouble shoot this and every tip would be highly appreciated.

The bash text is (sorry for long text):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./notebook.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
```

....
    Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

```
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.


No file notebook.aux.

*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: xetex
* paper: <default>
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(72.26999pt, 469.75502pt, 72.26999pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(72.26999pt, 650.43001pt, 72.26999pt)
* \paperwidth=614.295pt
* \paperheight=794.96999pt
* \textwidth=469.75502pt
* \textheight=650.43001pt
* \oddsidemargin=0.0pt
* \evensidemargin=0.0pt
* \topmargin=-37.0pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=11.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=59.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidefalse
* \@mparswitchfalse
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)



Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.



LaTeX Warning: No \author given.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/se-ascii-print.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmtt.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ppl.fd) [1]
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.341 function for three types of agents, \$\alpha
                                                  - \$, \(\beta-\) type of
? 
! Emergency stop.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.341 function for three types of agents, \$\alpha
                                                  - \$, \(\beta-\) type of
Output written on notebook.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on notebook.log.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having an error in the compile. See [Issue 893](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/893). I had a similar problem today, running on a Windows machine. I only got a single pdf page out of a five page document.

I selected "download as LaTex/Tex" (in open Jupyter notebook session) then opened that tex file in my TeX editor (TeXworks). It may be zipped if you have images, just extract the file(s) if so.

I then compiled with Xelatex, which tripped on the error and showed it (in the compile log) to be simply a blank space I left between an inline LaTex "$" delimiter and the beginning of some LaTex. I removed the blank space so I had "$\mathrm{MeV}" instead of "$ \mathrm{MeV}" and it compiled fine.

I subsequently tested a direct "download as PDF from LaTex" in my Jupyter notebook on the corrected ipnyb file and it performed perfectly.